# oracle search using duplicate values - how do I return duplicate results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to return values from a SELECT statement, regardless of if they are duplicate or not.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE_TABLE
WHERE PERSON_ID = 1
AND PERSON_ID = 1;
```

It obviously just returns a single record e.g.

```
(person_id, name) 
       "1", "Henry"
```

I would like my results to return

```
"1", "Henry"
"1", "Henry"
```

What's the best way to achieve this?  My actual joins a few tables and uses WHERE IN and then specifies about 600 values (200 unique values).

Comment: UNION ALL with the same select.

Comment: Add more tables and sample data, and it will be easier to understand what problem to solve.

Comment: `WHERE IN` could be surpressing duplicates, using a join instead would not. But it's hard to tell quote what you're doing and how to replace it, so a larger example would be helpful - not necessarily your full real code, but a minimal example that shows the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WHERE IN` will suppress duplicates. If you're doing something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_TABLE (PERSON_ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO PEOPLE_TABLE VALUES (1, 'Henry');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE_TABLE VALUES (2, 'George');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE_TABLE VALUES (3, 'Jane');

SELECT PERSON_ID, NAME
FROM PEOPLE_TABLE
WHERE PERSON_ID IN (1, 1, 3);

 PERSON_ID NAME      
---------- ----------
         1 Henry      
         3 Jane
```

Then you can join instead, against a table collection that contains the same target values:

```
SELECT PT.PERSON_ID, PT.NAME
FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 1, 3)) T
JOIN PEOPLE_TABLE PT
ON PT.PERSON_ID = T.COLUMN_VALUE;

 PERSON_ID NAME      
---------- ----------
         1 Henry      
         1 Henry      
         3 Jane
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ab4d/1). (Or [with strings](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf00c/1), from a comment).

You can create your own schema-level table collection type if you prefer and have privileges to do that, or use [a built-in one like `SYS.OCDINUMBERLIST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#sthref757) or [`SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#sthref759), depending on your actual data type.

Comment: thanks Alex but I'm working in a restricted environment with only a few privileges.  The actual strings I'm searching for are randomly generated 5 digit keys.  I would have just created a temp table to do what you're saying but I don't have the rights.

Comment: I'm not creating a temporary table object, this is all in memory. If you can't create your own type and have string, you can use [sys.odcivarchar2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#sthref759) instead. The principle is the same. You do need to be able to construct your query with the list of values in that table clause rather than in an `IN` clause, but that isn't a privilege issue.

Comment: @edw - maybe also worth mentioning the limit of 1000 items in any list. If you have that many values it might be better to populate a (maybe global temporary) table and join to that; but then you would have to have the privs to create that GTT as a one-off action.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the result, use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE_TABLE
WHERE PERSON_ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM PEOPLE_TABLE
WHERE PERSON_ID = 1
```

Actually, I think you're asking for something else, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your PERSON_ID is a number

You only need one criteria

```
select * from PEOPLE_TABLE
where PERSON_ID = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ff40/5

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are duplicate values in the search clause, not in the table.

Comment: I'd say I just realize what he was asking after seeing your solution. I still don't find the use for it but yeah, good one.

Comment: I'm not 100% I've understood the question yet either, but that's my best guess *8-)